# -bash: manage.py: command not found while trying to run a git project

Tags: python, django, git

I am trying for the first time to run the project from the git. Here is the link to the project:
https://github.com/spilab-umich/phishing-warning-experiment
I followed all the suggested steps to deploy a Django on a host and it worked fine. I run: python manage.py runserver and after that wanted to come to the importing mail module,typing:
python manage.py makemigrations mail
I get the error message: -bash: manage.py: command not found
Have anyone idea what I am doing wrong? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: That repo is missing the `manage.py`. I'm surprised that `python manage.py runserver` didn't fail as well, unless you switched directories after running that command. You could create the `manage.py` by running `django-admin startproject website` in another folder, then copy the `manage.py` file to the `phishing-warning-experiment/mail_client/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you typed `python manage.py makemigrations` and not `manage.py makemigrations`?